# Google Maps: Event listener finds only the latest added object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I have a mouseover function on multiple polygons but when I mouseover the polygon I added first, the event listener always use the latest added polygon.

Here is my code:

EDITED after Jons suggestions. Google Maps seems to hang with this code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Polygon Simple</title> 
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(64.75539,11.557617);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var counties = [
        [ new google.maps.LatLng(65.5938045448117, 18.1841615957621), new google.maps.LatLng(65.60908024341229, 18.0771327994505), new google.maps.LatLng(65.648282356232, 17.797014589131), new google.maps.LatLng(65.6726402881329, 17.6650173420103), new google.maps.LatLng(66.05487225660011, 16.7827851638447), new google.maps.LatLng(66.0563835399301, 16.5826047275627), new google.maps.LatLng(66.30204247803511, 15.826110215697), new ... ],
        [ new google.maps.LatLng(60.2679550905311, 13.9522771739341), new google.maps.LatLng(60.1898004284838, 13.9706839102235), new google.maps.LatLng(60.2696058042898, 13.8508890937951), new google.maps.LatLng(60.4187463068127, 13.6952984208179), new google.maps.LatLng(60.4226284842923, 13.5706921611819), new google.maps.LatLng(60.448328778914, 13.4996704338411), new ... ]
    ];

    var polygons = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < counties.length; i++)
    {
        polygons[i] = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: counties[i],
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#FF0000",
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          isSelected: false
        });

        polygons[i].setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(polygons[i],'click',function(event) {
            toggleSelection(polygons[i]);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(polygons[i],'mouseover',function(event) {
          polygons[i].setOptions({ fillOpacity: 0.45 });
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(polygons[i],'mouseout',function(event) {
            if (!polygons[i].isSelected)
            {
              polygons[i].setOptions({ fillOpacity: 0.35 });
            }
        });
    }
  }

  function toggleSelection(polygon)
  {
    if (polygon.isSelected)
    {
      polygon.setOptions({ fillOpacity: 0.35 });
      polygon.isSelected = false;
    }
    else
    {
      polygon.setOptions({ fillOpacity: 0.45 });
      polygon.isSelected = true;
    }
  }
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, post an answer and accept it. Answers/solutions do not go in questions.

Comment: At the time I couldn't create my own answer, at least for another eight hours, so I posted the answer in my main post instead. Did you remove the answer from the post?

Comment: Yes. If you have to wait before writing an answer in the correct place, then wait... but don't just write it in the wrong place instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store every polygon in an array, and then add the event listener for each element of the array. Otherwise, you're rewriting the event listener for the latest polygon. I had to do the same with a bunch of markers in my application. It's unfortunate for memory consumption, but as long as you aren't dealing with hundreds of polygons then you'll be alright.

```
var polygons = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < whatever; i++) {
    polygon[i] = new Polygon(stuff);
    event.addListener(polygon[i], moreStuff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it seems as if the code hangs. I have updated my main post with my current code.

Comment: Hmm. Your code looks good as far as I can tell. How many polygons are you creating? It looks like it's just 2. Is that correct? By hangs, what specifically hangs?

Comment: When I first try to mouseover one of the pylogons, it hangs. As you  can see in the code, the mouseovered polygon should change opacity, but nothing happens, and it's all in a very hangy fashion, so I do not suspect any syntax errors. And yes, there are two pylogons.

Comment: That's interesting. It might be worthwhile to use a javascript debugger, such as Firebug (for Firefox) to get to the root of the problem. Best of luck.

Comment: Ah, it's the for-loop. Since I already did two iterations, i is on 2 (its third iteration), which makes the code fetch index 2 in the polygons array, which obviously don't exist. So the problem lies in the way I build the event listeners. The spontaneous solution would be to pass the polygon into the event function as an argument, but I don't know how to do that. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that is your problem. In your for loop you have i < counties.length, which means i will only get to one. And when you add the event listener for each polygon, it already is sort of an argument, as your specifying which polygon to add the listener for.

Comment: Alright. If my solution helped, please mark it as an answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to you: I'm using KML polygons as highlighting layers above my marker layers; I used this code to disable the onclick (so my marker areas will click, but not the polygon layer). HTH

```
function createLayers() {
var layerRest = new google.maps.KmlLayer('earth.kml', {preserveViewport:true, clickable: false});
layerRest.setMap(map);


polylayers.push(layerRest); // Layer # 0        
}
```